# pip install syntax for allowing insecure

Tags: python, pip

I tried to run

```
$pip install --upgrade --allow-insecure setuptools
```

but it doesn't seem to work?
is my syntax wrong?

this is on ubuntu 13.10
I need --allow-insecure as I haven't been able to the get the 
corporate proxy SSL certificates yet so I always get certificate verify failed errors.

I get this error:

```
You must give at least one requirement to install (see "pip help install")
```

Comment: Please include the actual error traceback as well.

Comment: Pip doesn't really have an option for this. Try installing it from a HTTP source: `pip install --upgrade --index-url=http://pypi.python.org/simple/ setuptools`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The current syntax is to use `--trusted-host`, to allow insecure downloads of all packages from a specific host or hosts.

```sh
pip install setuptools --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org
```

If you specify a custom PyPI repository either via a `pip.conf` or `--index-url my.own.pypi.repo`, you'll want to use your own repo instead of `pypi.org`.

Answer (score 6):

`--allow-insecure` takes a package as an argument. So you want:

`$ pip install --upgrade --allow-insecure setuptools setuptools`