# how to fix pip3 mac

Tags: python, macos, pip

Over 2 monthes, I can't install any packages with pip3.
Everytime I try it is sending the same messages :
[image: pip3]

I'd like to know how to fix that, because I know I already saw on stackoverflow another command with pip that worked with me to install packages but I don't remember and I can't find the subject again.
I hope you could help me ^^
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mac OSX python ssl.SSLError: \[SSL: CERTIFICATE\_VERIFY\_FAILED\] certificate verify failed (\_ssl.c:749)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42098126/mac-osx-python-ssl-sslerror-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certificate-verify)

Comment: try `pip3 install --allow-insecure pygame`
refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21083268/pip-install-syntax-for-allowing-insecure

Comment: Thank you but it is sending me : no such option: --allow-insecure

Comment: Will you please add the output of `pip --version` to the question?

Comment: pip 21.2.3 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip (python 3.10)

Comment: Just a tip: it would be more helpful to copy the text of the error in a code block, rather than screenshotting it. Makes it easier to read, copy-paste, etc. See http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/

Answer (score -2):

Try repairing with python installer. https://www.python.org/downloads/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).